# Including an exception class in a header file

Tags: c++, exception

I have a pair of files, say `Foo.cpp` and `Foo.hpp` that define a class, say `Foo`. `Foo`'s methods have the potential to throw an exception, defined in the file `MyException.hpp`, but `Foo.hpp` does *not* need `MyException`.

Obviously the `.cpp` needs to include the exception header, but should I include the exception header in `Foo.hpp` instead to allow any files that use `Foo` to have a definition of the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual rule of thumb is that every file should include the headers that it needs. So, no, don't add `MyException.hpp` to `Foo.hpp` unless it's needed there. Code that deals with your exception class should `#include "MyException.hpp"`. So, obviously, whichever files implement the member functions that throw this exception need to `include "MyException.hpp"`, and any files that include code that catch this exception also need it.

Comment: Out of interest, how does the standard library do it? It has the potential to throw exceptions, but do the headers include the exception headers?

Comment: @Xenopathic - it depends on how the standard library is implemented. Dinkumware's library uses functions to throw exceptions; that avoids having the code that throws the exception inserted wherever a throw occurs, and the functions typically go in a separate implementation file. The implementation file has to see the appropriate headers, but the headers don't necessarily include the headers that define the exceptions. More generally, though, there are some complicated interrelationships between standard library headers, so you'll usually end up seeing the exception headers in many places.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you derive your custom exception from std::exception.

Now there are two use cases (I imagine):

- The exception is informative, nothing can be done to resolve it.
  Hence nobody will care about the actual type (you may keep it the source).
- The exception is specific and an action can resolve it:
  Make the exception type public in the header.

Most of the exceptions I have seen are informative, there is nothing to resolve the state of objects affected.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'informative' or 'specific' - could you clarify?

Comment: @Xenopathic informative would be something like "sorry, you can not resolve this error" - specific to an action would be something like "internal state not changed, due to ..."

Comment: But surely for generic coding, you should not differentiate between the two types of error? In some code you might want to catch 'informative' exceptions, while in others you might want to catch 'specific' exceptions

Comment: @Xenopathic Surly, catch any exception, but what are the steps after that?

Comment: For some programs where the error is 'unresolvable' you would clean up resources and try again, for some programs where the error is 'resolvable' you might want to error out since your program requires that functionality to be working without a workaround

Answer (score -1):

It is considered a good style to make each `.h` file *self-sufficient*, so that each header would include/provide all features it needs. Given that, it makes sense to include `MyException.hpp` in `Foo.hpp`. That way, users of `Foo.h` will not endure compile-time errors when they just include it in their code.

Comment: There's nothing in the question that indicates that `Foo.hpp` would not compile without `MyException.hpp`. In fact, the later edit indicates that it **doesn't** need `MyException.hpp` to compile.

Comment: But the class header itself does not require `MyException` to be defined - just the `.cpp` does. Does the fact that the class may at some point throw `MyException` count as a feature that the header should provide?

Comment: If the class throws a certain exception, it is part of its public interface, even if it is not mentioned in `.h` file. Which suggests it to be included as such.

Answer (score -2):

Only include the MyException.hpp header in you Foo.hpp file. Let your Foo.cpp include only the Foo.hpp header. The .cpp file is only meant for the implementation of the interface declared in the header file. The .cpp should not contain any other includes part from it's own header.